# Wordpress/Woocommerce how to customize wc_display_item_meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have some custom meta values which gets rendered in an `unordered-list` which is fine but I would like to know if it is possible to customize the output?

As mentioned `wc_display_item_meta` displays:

```
<ul class="wc-item-meta">
  <li>
     <strong class="wc-item-meta-label">My label</strong> 
     <p>My custom data</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So, is it possible to change that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass arguments to the `wc_display_item_meta()` function that allow you to customize parts of the markup. These are the default values but you can change them to whatever you need.

```
wc_display_item_meta($item, array(
    'before'    => '<ul class="wc-item-meta"><li>',
    'after'     => '</li></ul>',
    'separator' => '</li><li>',
));
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is actually NOT to use that function and use the following foreach loop.

That way you get hold of meta data as an object and can choose which keys and values to display, format them as you wish etc. You get the idea using this instead of wc_display_item_meta()

```
foreach ( $item->get_formatted_meta_data() as $meta_id => $meta ) {
     print_r($meta);
}
```

Function wc_display_item_meta() itself uses it. See http://hookr.io/functions/wc_display_item_meta/