# How to get rid of internal <p> tags of wc_display_item_meta() in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

Is there a way, that we can get rid of the internal `<p>` tags of `wc_display_item_meta()` in the `email-order-items.php`. Currently, it returns the values like this.

**Color:**

- Blue

**Size:**

- XL

In which the **Blue** and **XL** are inside the `<p>` tags. I want it to display it like

**Color:** Blue

**Size:** XL

The `wc_display_item_meta()` has parameters of `$item` and array of arguments.
These arguments include

```php
'before'    => '<ul class="wc-item-meta"><li>',  
'after'     => '</li></ul>',  
'separator' => '</li><li>',`
```

But no matter what I put in the arguments, it has the internal `<p>` tag for the values of the metadata.

Any help will be appreciated in this regard. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress/Woocommerce how to customize wc\_display\_item\_meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498710/wordpress-woocommerce-how-to-customize-wc-display-item-meta)

Comment: @Core972 No it is not the duplicate of that question. I have read the answer to that question before asking this question. But anyway Thanks

Comment: Can u share the html structure using inspect element. I can help you with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try this

```
<div class="my-class">
 <?php echo wc_display_item_meta(); ?>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-class p {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/epm1t2fv/